# CSS file not loading when using WAMP server

Tags: apache, wamp, localserver

WAMP server loading index.html just fine but not loading any additional css style sheets and script files.

I've tried these

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wamp/www/AngularJS_Practice/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
```

edit

My current index.html page is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
<head>

<title>Electronic Components</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>


</body>
</html>
```

edit 2
    css

```
h2 {

color: orange;
font-style: italic;

 }
```

Comment: Show us your file tree

Comment: The file tree for the index file is C:\wamp\www\AngularJS_Practice\index.html 
and the file tree for the css file is
C:\wamp\www\AngularJS_Practice\css\style.css

Comment: it is preferred to write <!DOCTYPE html> ,  also UTF-8(uppercase)

Comment: Your html file seems to be correct , css file may have a error , can you add style.css too ?

Comment: Just added the css file (its very short because I'm using WAMP for the first time)

Comment: The file seems to be correct , open developer's tool(ctrl+shift+i for chrome) and see the sources tab , do you see style.css over there ?

Comment: I see it there, along with the css folder the stylesheet is in

Answer (score 4):

Refresh your browser cache. Press 'Ctrl+F5'
That'll do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".\style.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to use type

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Also note

```
 <link ....>  // this is right
 <link ..../> // avoid this
```

---

Your HTML file seems right , try making this small css file in css folder and link to it

```
body{background-color:blue;}
```

Test this

Comment: Also remember that you have to link it in <head> tag.If you have a folder css in your working directory that contains style.css then this should work fine.

Comment: I tried adding type="text/css" but it the css still doesn't appear and yeah its in the head tag

Comment: Also see the code you pasted it has <link ..../> which is not right check this in you index.html.                                                                                                     It would be better if you would upload the code of index.html for better understanding.

Comment: I just posted the index contents above

Comment: `type` is optional. XHTML style self-closing tags are required in XHTML and allowed in HTML 5.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same issue and what worked for me is this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

Enjoy

Answer (score -1):

select the full url from url bar and then press ENTER... It works! ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To me it is unclear how this would solve the OP's question. Please expand and clarify the steps and why it works.

Comment: when you select the url and then prress ENTER the header information is resent to the server(whether that be your local server or remote one)...since new header information is resend to the server a new page is requested from the server and hence your page will be refreshed and everything will work... If this don't work then try restarting your servers...HOPE IT HELPS